# Xperia V can I relock my bootloader for Bravia Engine to work again?

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, sony-xperia-v

I have unlocked the bootloader to try some roms, but too late I understand that this will make the Bravia Engine to stop working...
If I relock my bootloader will that make the Bravia Engine to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just relocking won't work, you need to restore the *TA partition* (which contains DRM keys for Bravia Engine) that you must have backed up **before** unlocking your bootloader.

Comment: so is it reversable?

Comment: @БориславМинчев: If you have a TA backup yes, if not no.